# Make Vim open every file read-only

Tags: vim

I wish to make Vim open every file in read-only mode.

My use case is that I use Vim as both my editor and a gdb frontend via the Pyclewn plugin. I typically have one instance of Vim open for editing and another for debugging. I wish that the debugging instance would always open source files in read-only mode so that I do not get the ".swp file already exists" prompt, or that I accidentally edit a file without meaning to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a special command for this: `view FILENAME`

Or: `vim -R FILENAME`

For other cool things, see the man page for vim(1):
`man 1 vim`

Comment: Oh, right, of course. I just didn't think to start it as view instead of vim ;) .